# How Create Charts with the Google Chart API in asp.net?

Tags: charts

How to Creat  Charts with the Google Chart API in asp.net?

Answer (score 4):

Google is a good place to start...

[Google Charts API as ASP.NET 2.0 Server Control](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2007/12/Google-Charts-API-an-ASPNET-20-Server-Control.aspx)

[Google Chart Net](http://www.codeplex.com/GoogleChartNet)

Or better yet use the new ASP.NET charting control

[ASP.NET Charting Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the article on 4guysfromrolla

[Creating charts with Google chart API with ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20210612113532/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111908-1.aspx)

[ASP.NET Custom Server Control for Google chart](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616113733/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/112608-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

FYI there are plenty of Google Chart API [wrapper APIs](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chart-api/web/useful-links-to-api-libraries) that will make your life easier in terms of dealing with low-level Google Chart API details. I wrote one the Java side (called [charts4j](http://charts4j.googlecode.com)). But there is also at least one wrapper API in the .NET arena.

I am not completely familiar with the ASP .Net stack, but you will probably want to generate the the Google Chart URL server side, and display that URL with your HTML view technology in an image tag. The alternative is to pass the data to the browser and construct the chart URL with javascript, but this is likely to be more tedious and error prone. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that hard, things to consider are
1. Build up your data table for chart and save it to Json format
2. Use jquery function getJson to retrieve it, then follow google API on how to
   Parse Json file, then there is the graph
I built lots of graphs by using this method using C#

Comment: TheMissionPossible:Can you give simple sample to validate your points?